# Displaying asp.net mvc 4 web app in IE 7 to 10 differ from versions

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4

I am programming an asp.net mvc 4 web app using the internet application template. I have observed that the menu of the template at the top right, that which says: Home Contact About..
is not being shown in IE 7 but it is shown in IE 8, 9, 10.

So my issues are:

```
1) Why the menu is not shown in IE7 but it is shown in IE 8, 9, 10.
2) The menu shown in iE 8, 9 and 10 differ, the item are not
positioned in the same way.
```

Could somebody help me?

this is my _layout view, the master page:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">

            <div class="float-left">
                <section>@Html.ActionLink(
                                 " ",
                                 "Index",
                                 "Home",
                                 new
                                 {
                                    style = "background: url('" + Url.Content("~/images/HeaderLogo.gif") + "') no-repeat center left; display:block;  height:33px; width:162px;"
                                 }
                         )                    
                </section>

                <section>
                    <p class="site-title">@Resources.Resource.HeaderAppTitle</p>
                </section>                   
            </div>

            <div class="float-right">
                <table>
                <tr>
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")                                   
                </section>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                @Html.Partial("_CulturePartial")                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <nav id="NavigationMenu">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <!--<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>-->
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tests", "Index", "Tests")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Configure", "Configure", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        <div class="errorMessage">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.ValidationMessage("errMessage")
        </div>

        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-right">
                <p>&copy; Copyright @Resource.CompanyName @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")


    @*@Content.Script("jquery-1.10.2.min.js", Url)*@
    @*@Content.Script("jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js", Url)*@
    @Content.Script("jquery-1.9.1.js", Url)
    @Content.Script("jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js", Url)
    @Content.Script("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", Url)
    @Content.Script("jquery.dd.js", Url)
    @Content.Script("grid.locale-en.js", Url)        
    @Content.Script("jquery.jqGrid.min.js", Url)

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

and this is the partial views, _CulturePartial:

```
<div id="flagsGroup">
     <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "es-ES", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })"><img src="~/images/SpanishFlag.png" alt="Change page language to spanish."/></a>
     <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "ca-ES", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })"><img src="~/images/CatalanFlag.png" alt="Change page language to catalan."/></a>
     <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = "en-GB", returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })"><img src="~/images/BritishFlag.png" alt="Change page language to english."/></a>
</div>
```

and _LoginPartial:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
        }
    </text>
} else {
    @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
}
```

**UPDATE:**

IF i click on internet explorer compatibility mode I get an error in jquery-1.9.1.js in this piece of code: (in fact here is advised that ie6/7 do not support getting/setting...)

```
// IE6/7 do not support getting/setting some attributes with get/setAttribute
if ( !getSetAttribute ) {

    // Use this for any attribute in IE6/7
    // This fixes almost every IE6/7 issue
    nodeHook = jQuery.valHooks.button = {
        get: function( elem, name ) {
            var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            return ret && ( name === "id" || name === "name" || name === "coords" ? ret.value !== "" : ret.specified ) ?
                ret.value :
                undefined;
        },
        set: function( elem, value, name ) {
            // Set the existing or create a new attribute node
            var ret = elem.getAttributeNode( name );
            if ( !ret ) {
                elem.setAttributeNode(
                    (ret = elem.ownerDocument.createAttribute( name ))
                );
            }
```

**BELOW LINE IS WHERE IT CRASHES**

```
                          ret.value = value += "";

            // Break association with cloned elements by also using setAttribute (#9646)
            return name === "value" || value === elem.getAttribute( name ) ?
                value :
                undefined;
        }
    };

    // Set contenteditable to false on removals(#10429)
    // Setting to empty string throws an error as an invalid value
    jQuery.attrHooks.contenteditable = {
        get: nodeHook.get,
        set: function( elem, value, name ) {
            nodeHook.set( elem, value === "" ? false : value, name );
        }
    };

    // Set width and height to auto instead of 0 on empty string( Bug #8150 )
    // This is for removals
    jQuery.each([ "width", "height" ], function( i, name ) {
        jQuery.attrHooks[ name ] = jQuery.extend( jQuery.attrHooks[ name ], {
            set: function( elem, value ) {
                if ( value === "" ) {
                    elem.setAttribute( name, "auto" );
                    return value;
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the `compatibility mode icon`, this should work to display the menu.  The issue is down to the CSS not being rendered properly I guess.

[`Fix Display problems with compatibility mode`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-10).

Comment: I have googled and here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp I a not sure if nav tag is supported in previous versions of IE 9. It says it is supported in IE9 but in previous ones? maybe this is the cause.... i do not know...

Comment: Clicking on compatibility mode makes it crash, see my updated post.

Comment: Is updating the browser not an option? since 7 is old

Comment: maybe, but it is Windows server 2003 and I am not sure if client will agree.... it does not depends on me...